# Chrome SVG clip-path behave incosistent across monitors

Tags: google-chrome, svg, scaling, clip-path, hidpi

So I have a small HTML snippet below,

```html
<p style="clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100px 0, 100px 10px, 0 10px)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="100">
  <text y=16 clip-path="polygon(0 0, 100px 0, 100px 10px, 0 10px)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</text>
</svg>
```

I expected the `svg` to be clipped as `p` does. Something like this below,

[image: expected one]

But moving this to my other monitor, which runs at 125% scaling, it changes,

[image: 125% scaling]

Then I tried with the Macbook, which runs at 200% scaling, and the clip is gone .

[image: 200% scaling]

I found the alternative solution, which is by using [`Window.devicePixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) to correctly scale the `clip-path` (because the SVG is generated on the fly).

The problem is that this only happens on Chrome (and other Chromium-based). While on Firefox it's consistent across all monitors. So which browser is the correct behavior? Is this bug for Chrome? I can't find any existing questions about this on StackOverflow.

Thanks,

edit: oh yeah I just found it's been on bug tracker since 2018 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=800784

Comment: Sounds like something you should report to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: oh yeah. I just found this issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=800784
welp it's been years it's still open 

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the `clip-path` to the SVG, rather than the `<text>`, it behaves as your expect.

```html
<p style="clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100px 0, 100px 10px, 0 10px)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="100" clip-path="polygon(0 0, 100px 0, 100px 10px, 0 10px)">
  <text y="16">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't put it on the `svg` because there are a lot of elements inside it, not just the text 